Why this source transformation leads to different current on 3-ohm resistor?
I am trying to find the current across the 3-ohm resistor(which equals to 2A), and I noticed that when I perform a source transformation, the result is incorrect. I suspect this may be because of the resistor itself is involved in the source transformation. However, when I reverse the voltage source polarity, I get the correct results.
I tried experimenting with different R1 values to see if this was just a coincidence, and it seems like it is not. What I am missing?


Can you show your calculations that are in conflict with each other?

Why haven't you combined R2, R4 and R4 because they are all reduceable to one resistor. You must learn to look at a circuit and see what is presented in front of you before doing any mathematics. It's called "simplification". I strongly advise you simplify first because it gives you a fundamental insight into the problem.

When converting a norton current source to a thevenin voltage source,  you would want to put the voltage source under the 3 ohm resistor.

@periblepsis I check currents in simulations. The original circuit was current source one and current on 3-ohm res. reads 2A downwards. However making this conversion yields -1A.

@Andyaka I actually solved question much more efficiently, but I just don't understand why this is not working.

@AmitM Can you explain how do I decide place of voltage source?

When calculating thevenin equivalent of the norton current circuit, the thevenin resistance should be put after the voltage source. Here, 3 ohm resistor is the thevenin resistor of the thevenin source $V_3$..

When you do a conversion between Thevenin and Norton equivalents you're not interested in the voltages and currents within the equivalent, you're interested in the effect of the equivalent on the rest of the circuit. You treat the equivalent as a black box with two terminals.
What you will find is that if you make the current in R1 match in the Norton and Thevenin versions by reversing the voltage source polarity, the currents and voltages in the rest of the circuit will be wrong. If you put the voltage source the way the convention for doing the conversion tells you to, the rest of the circuit works out the way it should.
What you are seeing is normal, you're just trying to measure inside the "black box".
Let's look at an example:

Here we have a Norton equivalent and a Thevenin equivalent, the same as in your problem, but with just a 1Ω resistor connected to each. In the Norton, most of the current will go through the 1Ω resistor due to the current divider rule. In the Thevenin the same current goes through both the 3Ω and 1Ω resistors. The current through both 1Ω resistors is 2.25 A, while the current through the 3Ω resistors is different (0.75 A vs. 2.25 A). So we can expect that the current through the resistors internal to the equivalent circuits can be different (except when the external resistance is the same as the internal resistance, then the internal resistor current is the same for both Norton and Thevenin).
Also note that in LTspice resistors have a polarity even though you don't normally see it. If you hold the cursor over them it will show a direction of current flow. Rotating the resistor will reverse this direction, so the orientation of resistors will affect whether the current through them shows as positive or negative in the results.

Hopefully this communicates well to the OP. It touches everything needed, including the specific details about LTspice and the sign of the value it reports for resistors. Nice!

Voltage sources in LTspice also have a non-intuitive current flow direction which confuses users. Might be worth pointing this out too? I dunno. The cursor thing is a good tip but doesn’t work in sims which don’t use the the waveform viewer (i.e. .op or .ac at a single frequency).

Thanks. I will look into that resistor polarity thing as well.

I don't remember ever having to do a source transformation in all my years, but Wikipedia has an illustration:

Image source: Source transformation.
Note that the node connected to the source of the current is connected in the voltage transform to connect to the positive of the voltage source.

A brief proof of the theorem
The transformation can be derived from the uniqueness theorem. In the present context, it implies that a black box with two terminals must have a unique well-defined relation between its voltage and current. It is readily to verify that the above transformation indeed gives the same V-I curve, and therefore the transformation is valid.

It appears that your V3 is connected in reverse.
